# Could not save; currently locked by another user. OledbException was unhandled

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a background worker thats doing some database work for me. The reason why I resorted to using using the background worker is because the database work is taking up a lot of time. So the code works the first time but as you continue to update the database then then you get "Could not save; currently locked by another user. OledbException was unhandled". Is the a way to go around this issue. This is my code

```
    Private Sub DoSaveUsersAuditForUpdate_Click()
    Dim myConn As OleDbConnection = frmLogIn.Conn
    SyncLock myConn
        'Insert Previous data before the Update
        'myConn = frmLogIn.Conn
        Dim cmdInsert As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Insert INTO UsersAudit (Reference,Comment) VALUES (?,?)", myConn)
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Reference", OleDbType.WChar).Value = txtReference.Text
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Comment", OleDbType.WChar).Value = "Update Existing Users Details"
        myConn.Open()
        cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myConn.Close()

    End SyncLock

    Dim myKonn As OleDbConnection = frmLogIn.Conn
    SyncLock myKonn
        'Insert Current data after the Update
        'myKonn = frmLogIn.Conn
        Dim cmdInsertOriginal As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Insert INTO UsersAudit (Reference,Comment) VALUES (?,?)", myKonn)
        cmdInsertOriginal.Parameters.Add("@Reference", OleDbType.WChar).Value = txtReference.Text
        cmdInsertOriginal.Parameters.Add("@Comment", OleDbType.WChar).Value = "New User"
        myKonn.Open()
        cmdInsertOriginal.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myKonn.Close()
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

Here's How I am calling it

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As        System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    DoSaveUsersAuditForUpdate_Click()
End Sub
```

this where it all comes together

```
    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)Handles  btnUpdate.Click
```

BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        'Dim workerThread As New Thread(AddressOf DoSaveUsersAuditForUpdate_Click)
        'workerThread.Start()
        DoUpdateUsers_Click(sender, e)
        UsersGridViewGridFormating()
End Sub

```
    Private Sub UsersGridViewGridFormating()
    Dim myConn As OleDbConnection = frmLogIn.Conn

    SyncLock myConn
        Dim iSql As String = "SELECT *   FROM  Users WHERE UserDeleted =@UserDeleted"

        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(iSql, myConn)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserDeleted", False)
        dTable.Clear()
        da.Fill(dTable)
        myConn.Close()
        Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(dTable)
        dv.Sort = "UserName asc"
        dTable = dv.ToTable

        UsersMasterGridview.DataSource = dTable                                  

        UsersMasterGridview.Visible = True

        UsersMasterGridview.Focus()

        lblNumberofRecords.Text = dTable.Rows.Count & " Records"

    End SyncLock

End Sub
```

Any Help this all the code I am using